# How can I format my array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-conversion, map-function

Need to format my array of objects to have a nested object.

Tried using map, and reduce. Can't seem to get the formatting correct.
Currently getting this.

```
[
  {
    "date": "2019-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "total": 20
  }
]
```

Need it to be in this format.

```
[
  {
    name: 'Total Call Volume',
    data: {
      '2019-01-01 00:00:00 -0800': 0,
      '2019-01-01 00:00:00 -0800': 88,

    }
  }
]
```

```
var arr = this.$store.state.aggregatedCallVolumeData;
var mapData = arr.map(item => ({
  date: item.startTime,
  total: item.dataValues.TOTAL_CALL_VOLUME
}));
var data = mapData.reduce((acc, value) => {
  acc[value.date] = acc[value.date] ? acc[value.date] : [];
  acc[value.date] ? acc[value.date].push(value.total) : [value.total];
  return acc;
}, {});

let result = Object.entries(data).map(d => ({ id: d[0] + ':' + d[1] }) );
console.log(result)
```

console output is

```
0: {id: "2019-10-27T00:00:00Z:0"}
1: {id: "2019-10-28T00:00:00Z:88"}
```

Comment: Could you describe the input data ?

Comment: mapData is  ````[
  {
    "date": "2019-10-01T00:00:00Z",
    "total": 20
  }
]````

Comment: How does "2019-10-01T00:00:00Z" maps to "2019-01-01 00:00:00 -0800"? They are not the same time.  And your output has two identical keys.  Do not say "it is just an example"; be precise if you want useful help.  Garbage in, garbage out.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj.data[item.date] = item.total;
  return obj;
}, {
  name: 'Total Call Volume',
  data: {}
})
```

something like that. You might need to switch around the 'obj' and 'item' param. Basically the obj param is the second argument in the reduce function. So the obj is that base object I added at the end, and the 'item' param is each item in the array. So we loop and keep adding the values on to the 'obj' and return it for the next loop to add onto

Comment: Didn't work for me, syntax errors and then when I fix those it says ````"TypeError: Cannot set property '2019-10-28T00:00:00Z' of undefined"````

Comment: Yea sorry corrected the syntax. That function will turn [ { date: , total: } , ] => { name: 'Total Call Volume', data: { date: total, } }

Comment: That worked! Is there any way I can get a comma after the item.total?

Comment: What do you mean a comma after item.total

Comment: So it prints out like this ````'2019-10-01T00:00:00Z': 20,```` instead of ````'2019-10-01T00:00:00Z': 20````

Comment: hmmm. I worried as to why you would want to do that. If you really need the comma you can turn the number into a string. Do something like obj.data[item.date] = item.total + ','

Comment: basically im trying to use my response.data in a chartkick.com/vue lineChart and I can't get it formatted correctly.